# How can I put a separator between every ListBoxItem in my ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Here's my XAML:

```
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="lstGames" Background="#343434" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Width="100"/>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Title:" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Release Date:" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ReleaseDate}" />
                        </StackPanel>                            
                    </StackPanel>                        
                </Grid>                                        
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>            
    </ListBox>
```

Sans putting a Rectangle and giving it a color inside of the DataTemplate, does the ListBox have some way of natively setting something in between every item?

Answer (score 20):

This is a better example because then you don't have a separator at the top

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>                
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Separator x:Name="Separator"/>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Separator" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: I agree that having the separator at the very top of the list is weird, but it might look fine at the bottom. For that, you can just move the `<Separator/>` below `<ContentPresenter/>` in the control template, which would also remove the need for the data trigger.

Comment: How can this be achieved with `ItemsControl`?

Comment: The separator display is not updated when items are added or removed so that a different item becomes the first one in the list. You need to call ListCollectionView.Refresh() to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

This builds on the answer @EvaLacy gave to be a little more complete.

Because that answer replaces the template of the `ListBoxItem`, it disables the built-in highlighting that occurs when selecting a list item (because the highlighting is done via triggers in the original template).  To get this functionality back, put the default triggers into the new template and tweak the template content a bit:

```xml
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>                
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Separator x:Name="Separator"/>

                        <!-- Bind to parent properties -->
                        <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                                Name="Bd"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"
                                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}"
                                              ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Separator" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    <!-- Original Triggers -->
                    <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Panel.Background" 
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Panel.Background"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>

                    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I retrieved these triggers using the old but useful [Show Me the Template](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/posts/details/2091) application.

Answer (score 3):

My solution:

```
 <Style x:Key="STYLE_ListBoxSubItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem">      
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <Separator x:Name="Separator" DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"/>
                    <Border x:Name="Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                </DockPanel>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Separator" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- Usage -->
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource STYLE_ListBoxSubItem}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can move the presentation of the separator into the `ListBoxItem` control template as in this intentionally simplified example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <PointCollection x:Key="sampleData">
            <Point>10,20</Point>
            <Point>30,40</Point>
            <Point>50,60</Point>
        </PointCollection>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource sampleData}">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Separator/>
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

This keeps the separator out of your item template.  The trade off is that you may need to copy more from the default `ListViewItem` control template to meet your needs.  Of course the `Separator` is one of only a dozen ways to visually render the separator.