# Data binding to a collection with different behavior for the last element

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate, itemspaneltemplate

This seems like it would be a common issue, but my Google-Fu left me empty-ended. Apologies if this has been asked a thousand times before!

I have a collection, say an `ObservableCollection<Athlete>`. I want to display that collection on screen so that it looks something like:

[Jersey Pic] | [Jersey Pic] | [Jersey Pic] | [Jersey Pic]

The key in this contrived example is the little bar, between each picture. Subtract that bar and it's just a `ListBox` bound to the collection, with a `ItemsPanelTemplate` of a horizontal `StackPanel`, and then an `ItemTemplate` to show the corresponding jersey picture for each item. No problems!

The question is then, how to append the bar, which could be any graphical element, after all but the last element in the collection?

Thank you!

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17990739/512365) may give you some ideas. They're adding a `Separator` to the `ControlTemplate` and using a `DataTrigger` to control the `Separator` `Visibility`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the link from @KornMuffin, you can put the bar in the left side of ListBox item :

| [Jersey Pic] | [Jersey Pic] | [Jersey Pic] | [Jersey Pic]

Then use `DataTrigger` with `{RelativeSource PreviousData}` binding, to hide the first bar if previous data is null. For example, assume that I'm using `Separator` to display the bar, I can add this style to the separator control to hide the first separator :

```
<Separator.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Separator">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Separator.Style>
```

Comment: Love it, I did not know that particular relative binding existed. Thank you!